# ASP.NET MVC - Scoped dependency injection with Web Application page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, lifecycle

In my ASP.NET MVC project, I am currently setting up a page with huge a search component that let's you search/filter a list of products.

Whenever you click on a filter, an HTTP request is made to the server to get the new filtered data (this data is located in the cloud).

With my current solution, whenever you filter something, an HTTP request is made but the BE needs to know the *previous* state of those filters on that specific page. In order to achieve that, I created a Cache class with SCOPED lifetime and it is injected into the controller.

At first it seemed obvious to me but now I am not so sure how it works and it's bothering me. Also, couldn't find documentation about this specific use case.

**Question**

This scoped class should be created per page request, that's clear. However, how come it persists in further AJAX calls? Shouldn't it be seen as a different request and therefore create a new instance?

I don't think the Controller is binds to the first page request, does it?

My current behavior is:

- Class is created per page request and is alive during further AJAX calls.

Can someone explain this to me? Is this the standard behavior? Or is this working fine because it's only in my local machine?

Comment: We can't guess what's going on without any code

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I will prepare a project example